# Avoid duplicates when records are inserting simultaneously in before insert hook

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a before insert hook which increments a number `batch_id` from latest entry for specific company (the group by statement).

However, if records are being inserted simultaneously, even in separate transactions, I end up with duplicate numbers.

Are there any alternatives or solutions to avoid duplicates from happening?

Here is my hook

```sql
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION before_orders_insert_trigger
  () returns TRIGGER
AS
  $$
BEGIN
  new.batch_id :=
  (
           SELECT   COALESCE(max(batch_id), 0) + 1
           FROM     orders
           WHERE    company_id = new.company_id
           GROUP BY company_id limit 1);
      RETURN new;
      END;
      $$ language 'plpgsql';
CREATE TRIGGER before_orders_insert_trigger before
INSERT
ON orders FOR each row EXECUTE PROCEDURE before_orders_insert_trigger();
```

Answer (score 0):

The traditional solution in PostgreSQL is to use a [SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE s;

INSERT INTO orders (batch_id, ...) VALUES (NEXTVAL(s), ...);
```

Or else use [SERIAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) as the column type for your primary key, which creates an internal sequence and makes sure to use it during INSERT.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    batch_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);
```

In MySQL, they don't have sequence objects. They implement a similar feature by using the [AUTO_INCREMENT option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) on the column.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  batch_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
);
```

Using a sequence or auto_increment is preferred over your method because it avoids the race conditions that you identified, which result in duplicate values when inserts run concurrently. It achieves this by using a global lock as it increments the sequence, so no two concurrent requests can be allocated the same value.

Read the documentation pages I linked to for more details.

---

Re your comment:

I see, you want a sequence that starts over for each group.

The only way to do that is to lock the set of rows for the given batch. Then calculate the max batch_id previously assigned to the same group, increment that value, and use it in an INSERT statement. Then release the lock.

If there are any concurrent requests, they have to wait for the lock. Once the lock is granted to them, they can query for the new max batch_id, with assurance that the previous request has finished their insert.

MySQL's outdated MyISAM storage engine supports a feature to allow the auto-increment column be the second column of a compound primary key. Thus it assigns values that start over for each distinct value of the first column.

```
CREATE TABLE myisam_orders (
  company_id INT NOT NULL,
  batch_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (company_id, batch_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

The only way this works is that MyISAM does table-level locking on writes. Any write to the table blocks other requests, so the one with the table lock has the freedom to calculate the max batch_id for the given company_id, without causing a race condition. The table-lock is released after the INSERT is complete.

The default storage engine, InnoDB, doesn't support the same behavior. Users of MySQL wanted to have many clients inserting concurrently. A table-level lock was a bottleneck for their throughput, because it made all the clients queue up for access.

If you have a highly concurrent application and don't want clients blocking each other for that table lock, then you may have to compromise by not having batch_id's that start over for each company.

Comment: Thank you Bill, The problem with a sequence is that I have to group records by company_id and then get the last batch_id based on that. As far as I read, this is not achievable using sequences. Please have a quick look at the hook I have. I appreciate the time you spent to answer me.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL, you can set your batch_id and other fields you don't want to have duplicates with a unique key then use INSERT IGNORE INTO to insert the data.